# How to check if all url parameters are given?

Tags: php, url

I have this url:

`localhost/moked/insert_event.php?custnumber=1234&event=E15&port=8088&areanumber=17`

I want to check if a user has changed this to e.g.:

`localhost/moked/insert_event.php?custnumber=1234`

I know how to check if a variable is empty, but I want to know if the user has taken a parameter out. How can I do that?

Comment: if(isset($_GET["variable"]))...

Comment: If our replies help you, then don't forget to upvote both answers and comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try{
    if(!isset($_GET['custnumber'])){
        throw new Exception('Missing "custnumber" parameter');
    }elseif(!isset($_GET['event'])){
        throw new Exception('Missing "event" parameter');
    }elseif(!isset($_GET['port'])){
        throw new Exception('Missing "port" parameter');
    }elseif(!isset($_GET['areanumber'])){
        throw new Exception('Missing "areanumber" parameter');
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

To do this for a single variable is quite easy:

```
if (!isset($_GET['event'])) {
    // event is missing
}
```

What most people don't know is that the `isset` command will take as many parameters as you care to give it.  You can check for all of the required parameters at once:

```
if (isset($_GET['custnumber'], $_GET['event'], $_GET['port'], $_GET['areanumber'])) {
    // all parameters are set
} else {
    // some are missing
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what so many developers fail to do when using isset() =o)

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
if( (!isset($_GET['event'])) || (!isset($_GET['port'])) || ... ) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: @MathieuImbert "That's what she said." because that's what everyone is thinking right now. :D

Answer (score 1):

Check if the required variables exist:

```
if (!isset($_GET['port'])) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try `isset($_GET['event'])`, `isset($_GET['port'])`, `isset($_GET['areanumber'])`

see [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

To check a list of variables:

```
$vars=array(
'var1'=>'Var1 Description',
'var2'=>'Var2 Description',
'var3'=>'Var3 Description');
$delim='';
$message='';
foreach($vars as $name=>$description)
{
    if(!isset($_GET[$name]))
    {
        $message.=$delim.$description;
        $delim=', ';
    }
}
if($message!=='')$message='Missing: '.$message;
```